# Assembly : Dealing with user input in windows nasm

Tags: windows, assembly, io, nasm

I'm a newbie to asm and trying to make a simple hello world which awaits for the user to press a key to end. For now the hello world is all good, but the .exe console program i got from this just close instantly while i want it to stay on screen untill the user press a key.
Now the problem i have is that for some reason, the program keep looping, searching for user input, but when i force close the program (^C) i can see all the keys i pressed are written on the next console line, like if it was using the wrong buffer (?)

I've been searching a fix all over the internet for a few days and finally I'm asking for help cuz this is driving me crazy ^^
Everything i found is mostly based on int system or under linux, while i have to deal with the windows api...

Thank you very much, any help or hint is welcome!

Code :

```
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   equ -11
STD_INPUT_HANDLE    equ -10 
NULL                equ 0

global start
extern ExitProcess, GetStdHandle, WriteConsoleA, ReadConsoleInputA

section .data
msg                 db "Hello World!", 13, 10, 0
msg.len             equ $ - msg
consoleInHandle     dd 1

section .bss
buffer              resd 2
buffer2             resd 2

section .text
    start:

        push    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
        call    GetStdHandle

        push    NULL
        push    buffer
        push    msg.len
        push    msg
        push    eax
        call    WriteConsoleA 

    read:

        push STD_INPUT_HANDLE
        call GetStdHandle
        mov [consoleInHandle],eax
        push consoleInHandle
        push dword[buffer2]
        push 1
        push NULL
        call ReadConsoleInputA

        cmp eax,1
        jge exit
        jmp read

    exit:

        push    NULL
        call    ExitProcess
```

Moar info about windows functions can be found here:

- [ReadConsoleInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961.aspx)
- [WriteConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `push dword [consoleInHandle]` (or just `push eax`) - you're pushing the address of the variable. I'm pretty sure you want `push buffer2` - the address, not `[contents]`. I suspect you're pushing them in the wrong order - handle should be last (less sure of this)...

Comment: thx @Frank, i modified that, but i'm afraid this doesn't solve the problem :/

I am still not able to detect any user input and when i force my program to stop i can see the chars i entered on the next command line...

And also, i'm pretty sure about the order of the arguments, as i checked them many times. Just give a quick look at the microsoft doc links i gave in my first post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push consoleInHandle` pushes the address, not the handle. You want `push dword [consoleInHandle]`. Conversely, for the buffer you want to pass the address, so you need `push buffer2` there. Also, this buffer should be the size of an `INPUT_RECORD` structure, which I believe is 32 bytes.

**Update**: As Frank commented, the argument order was also wrong.
This code works for me (note I had to add the `@xx` stdcall decorations due to how my environment is set up - apparently you don't need those):

```
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   equ -11
STD_INPUT_HANDLE    equ -10
NULL                equ 0

global start
extern ExitProcess@4, GetStdHandle@4, WriteConsoleA@20, ReadConsoleInputA@16

section .data
msg                 db "Hello World!", 13, 10, 0
msg.len             equ $ - msg
consoleInHandle     dd 1

section .bss
buffer              resd 2
buffer2             resb 32

section .text
    start:

        push    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
        call    GetStdHandle@4

        push    NULL
        push    buffer
        push    msg.len
        push    msg
        push    eax
        call    WriteConsoleA@20

    read:

        push STD_INPUT_HANDLE
        call GetStdHandle@4
        mov [consoleInHandle],eax
        push NULL
        push 1
        push buffer2
        push dword [consoleInHandle]
        call ReadConsoleInputA@16

    exit:

        push    NULL
        call    ExitProcess@4
```

Comment: Thanks, now i get were i was confused with the [] notation -_-

As for de INPUT_RECORD thing, do i have to do something like this?:
http://www.asmcommunity.net/board/index.php?topic=5983.0

Comment: nb I tried 
buffer2    resb 32
but this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Thanks :) This may sound like a foolish question but what library do i have to link to have this to work? It's compiling with nasm, but i get an error with my linker. I use GoLink : GoLink.exe /console /entry start simple_hw2.obj kernel32.dll and i get this error message : "The following symbols were not defined in the object file or files :- ExitProcess@4 GetStdHandle@4 WriteConsoleA@20 ReadConsoleInputA@16 Output file not made"

Comment: As I have written in the answer, you don't need the `@xx` suffixes. I use gnu mingw tools, which need it. Just delete them.

Comment: aaw this explains everything :$ and it works, woot! Thank you very much, i was getting very confused on this one ><